# Как установить вебхук на messaging platform в facebook api?

Tags: facebook, facebook-api

Я хочу напистать бот, который должен реагировать на сообщения от пользователей, которые пишут в сообщения страницы (Page) в FB. В разделе https://developers.facebook.com/apps/<>/messenger/ "Проверка приложения «Messenger»" я читаю:

`Для использования платформы Messenger вашему приложению потребуется одобрение на использование API Send/Receive (pages_messaging)...`

если я правильно понимаю, мне необходимо разрешение "`pages_messaging` - Позволяет вашему приложению отправлять и получать сообщения с помощью Страницы Facebook.". Я добавляю его к заявке, и далее FB говорит мне:

`Прежде чем вы можете отправить приложение на проверку, выполните следующие действия:
Укажите поле «URL-адрес политики конфиденциальности» для своего приложения. Чтобы сделать это, перейдите по следующей ссылке: Настройки.`

Дело в том, что я хочу использовать это разрешение в целях обучения, я не планирую как-то распространять свое приложение. Неужели мне обязательно надо составлять эту самую политику конфиденциальности? Или я что-то не правильно понял?